# How to read HDFS file from Akka Stream?

Tags: hdfs, akka-stream, akka-http

Can someone give an example to read a text file available at HDFS location through Akka Streaming? I'm a novice in Akka Stream and after googling so much not able to found any solution for the same.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Alpakka HDFS connector](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/hdfs.html), with which you can create a [`HdfsSource`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/hdfs.html#reading) to read from HDFS.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey Chung. Can I get an example using Alpakka HDFS connector to read HDFS files?

Comment: Hi @sumit, please check this https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/hdfs.html